# Ansible Error on One Box Stops Deploy on All Boxes

Tags: deployment, ansible

I'm building my first zero-downtime deploy with Ansible. I've made pre and post tasks around my deploy to take boxes out of the load balancer before updating them, and put them back in after, but I'd like to make things a bit more error-tolerant. I'm deploying a few boxes at a time, with `serial: n/2`. To make things more error tolerant, if an error occurs on one box I'd like the system to stop trying to deploy to all boxes, in case there was some problem with the code. How can I do this? Along a similar vein, are there any simple ways in Ansible to roll back in case of error? I've seen a few people do stuff like my latter request in what look like hacky ways, and am hoping for something canonical for both requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [maximum_fail_percentage](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#maximum-failure-percentage) to stop the playbook if too many hosts have failed.

Regarding rolling back - Ansible encourages 'failing forward' - i.e. if the deployment fails you should be able to run it again from the start to finish it. That's where Ansible's idempotency is helpful - previously completed tasks shouldn't make their changes twice.

If you really want to roll back, you can do it with a secondary playbook that you'll run of the first one fails. Ansible generates a list of the failed hosts in the playbook, so you can use that to limit the rollback playbook only to the hosts that failed:

```
ansible-playbook deploy.yml || ansible-playbook rollback.yml --limit @$HOME/deploy.retry
```

Comment: Great answer! Everything makes sense, but what I meant by rolling back is rolling back to a previous release of the app, in case something is wrong with the new code. Are there best practices detailed for such a situation somewhere?

Comment: Hm, not that I know of. Not specific to Ansible, anyway.